# Data in the TableView are removed (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**Data in the TableView is removed (Swift)**

I have a code for my application "**Notes**".

**But sometimes the data from the table is merely deleted .**

How can I fix this?

If you scroll the page back, the data will be erased

** I use to save and load data:**

```
func save() {
  UserDefaults.standard.set(myData, forKey: "notes")
  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
func load(){
    if let loadData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "notes") as? [String] {
        myData = loadData
        table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

[image: gif]

**ViewController 1**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
var myData: [String] = []
var selectedRow: Int = -1
var newRowText:String = ""
var detailView: DetailViewController!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    load()
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if selectedRow == -1 {
        return
    }
    myData[selectedRow] = newRowText
    if newRowText == "" {
        myData.remove(at: selectedRow)
    }
    table.reloadData()
    save()
}
@objc func AddNewNotes(){
    if table.isEditing{
        return
    }
    let name:String = ""
    myData.insert(name, at: 0)
    let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    table.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    table.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detail", sender: nil )
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myData.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    cell.textLabel?.text = myData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let detailView:DetailViewController = segue.destination as!DetailViewController
    selectedRow = table.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
    detailView.masterView = self
    detailView.setText(t: myData[selectedRow])
}
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `selectedRow` when the view reappears (`viewWillAppear` is called on return)?

Comment: Unrelated but **never** use `value(forKey:` to get a string array from `UserDefaults`. There is a dedicated method `stringArray(forKey:`

Comment: I agree @vadian's good point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data source array that you are filling the table view from is `myData`, it seems that you would need to call your `save()` method *before* reloading the table view (`table.reloadData()`) in the [viewWillAppear(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear) life cycle method:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // ...
    save()
    myTableView.reloadData()
    // ...
}
```

Also, (obviously) make sure that `myData` data source contains the saved desired data.

**However**, I would recommend to save the data before even leaving the second view controller, probably [viewWillDisappear(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621485-viewwilldisappear) would be a good place to do it; By applying this, there is no need to call `save()` in the first view controller anymore, all you have to do is to reload the table view. That would be more logical because the first view controller should displays the saved data, but not saving it, it shall be in the second view controller where you are adding data.

Comment: Can you describe in detail what is written in However, but I do not really understand(

Comment: What's the part that you are unable to understand?

Comment: I would recommend to save the data before and so on. PLS

Comment: The point is: you are saving the data once you came back to the first view controller which contains the table view, what you should do is saving the data before coming back to it, save it in the second view controller instead, that would be more logical.